# Is there an easy oneliner to make out of a string with numbers multiple floats? Using python

Tags: python, string

I have for example a string that goes: `1234 4321 3412` Is there a way that I can using python have three floats like this:

`float1: 1234 float2: 4321 float3: 3412`

I searches the web but i dont know how to formulat the sentence to find a solution,

Comment: what is the input and the desired output? Using also a better formatting for your question

Comment: `floats = [float(s) for s in text.split(" ")]`

Answer (score 0):

We can split the string by its space characters to create a list of 3 strings, and then map the float conversion across each string value to convert it into a float.

```py
s = "1234 4321 3412"
float1, float2, float3 = list(map(float, s.split(' ')))
```